# Error - 403 Forbidden, You are not allowed to access this page -

Tags: php, ios

I have an IOS app that is linked with PHP scripts located on my on my web server.

the problem:

I often get the error below (Sometimes I don’t) when my IOS app tries to retrieve data from my PHP script:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Forbidden [403]</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="100%">
<tr><td><font size="6"><b>403 Forbidden</b></font></td>
<td>
<p align="right"><a href="http://www.servage.net/" target="_black">
<img border="0" src="http://www.servage.net/img/content-logo.gif"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
You are not allowed to access this page. Possible problems:<ul>
  <li>Missing index file</li>
  <li>Misconfigured mod_rewrite settings in .htaccess</li>
  <li>Authentication Failure</li>
  <li>Incorrect file or folder permissions</li>
</ul>
<P>
<HR>
<ADDRESS><a href="http://www.servage.net/" target="_black">Servage.net</a> Clustered Webhosting running enhanced Apache Webserver</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

I don’t exactly know what can cause it, as I am retrieving informations from my php scripts using echos and working with this informations on my .m files. Can somoene tell me what can cause this problem?

**Edit:**

My PHP script is simple:

- I connect to the DB.
- Get what the user sent via the IOS app by POST request.
- Do some work with the db. (update , insert etc)
- Echo the results. (results can be anywhere from a table or a simple Integer)

Comment: You need to be logged in or/and also the user you are currentlu logdin has to have correct right to access this resource

Comment: Can we see your PHP script?

Comment: my php script does not need authentication to access it, so I don't think that is the problem @Vardius

Comment: I updated the question @Vortex11

Comment: it was simply the info what can couse it besides you already have this info at your response error. i suggest you to edit .htaccess file. Try to add `Options +FollowSymLinks`

Comment: I didn't understand fully what you meant by "the info what can couse it" ? can you please explain more